# Test code coverage all lines tested but not 100% on branches and statements

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, code-coverage, vuex

I thought my tests were complete , in the lreport I can see all lines covered... but I get

```
97.44% Statements 38/39 100% Branches 16/16 66.67% Functions 2/3 100% Lines 38/38
```

I re-tested adding non useful else branches and console logs ... every case is tested...

what's wrong with it ?

[image: spec files 1/2]

[image: spec file 2/2]

Comment: Looks like none of your tests wait long enough for `ticks(state)` to trigger. So that call is never tested and never asserted.

Comment: thanks I see now the red ... the tick(sate) is executed as the callback of an lolex time API for testing ... see my question/answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483236/vues-js-unit-test-mutations-cannot-complete-testing-of-function

Comment: so , I guess I need to skip over the test of  this line ...  don't know if possible like w istanbul ...

Comment: /* istanbul ignore next */ before  did the trick !! 100%

Answer (score 2):

As jesse found where was the issue ... I added the istanbul ignore ...

```
     [types.START] (state) {
        state.started = true
        state.paused = false
        state.stopped = false
        /* istanbul ignore next */
        state.interval = setInterval(() => tick(state), 1000)
        if (state.isWorking && state.soundEnabled) {
          Vue.noise.start()
        }
      },
```

and now the coverage is 100%...

Comment: You're welcome. You're still at 98%, but you're ignoring the remaining statements ;).